# Correctly Identify the sender of a chat message in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, chat

I am developing a chat application using VB.NET and ASP.NET and I need to identify the particular user name users post messages. At present, it just shows my name, even for messages I haven't posted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're going to have to give a bit more detail than this, post some code?

Answer (score 0):

The process running on the server is likely to run on your account.
You need users to login to your chat application.

Do you have a login page on your chat? How does it work?

Here are some posibiloties to start with:
Try to use membershi api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx
or login through

Use OpenId. (As is used here, when you login to Stack Overflow)

Comment: yes i am having login page where i am storing the user name in session and using it in chat page, is there any other way to get user name